# Why does TabLayout leave a gap for the NavBar when in immersive mode?

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-tablayout

I'm making a tabbed app using the Tabbed Activity template in Android Studio. The client wants the tabs at the bottom and it's for use in a kiosk so I have enables immersive mode etc just fine.

My draft layout looks like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The AppBarLayout is at the bottom however there's a gap below it for the hidden nav bar:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Bizzare! Try to go into your developer options and show the layout bounds to double check it's not margin/padding from any of your elements. A hacky solution would be to set a negative margin in the TabLayout with the dp of the current navbar size.

Comment: Great suggestions, however.... With layout bounds there are no bounds shown apart from the very end of the app's view being at the bottom of the screen. Setting the bottom margin actually hides the bottom of the tabLayout behind that invisible area!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be a simple fix, set fitsSystemWindows in the root view to false or remove it.

> The fitsSystemWindows attribute makes your ListView fit to the edges of the action bar and navigation bar (instead of going under them).

[Source](https://mindofaandroiddev.wordpress.com/tag/fitssystemwindows/)